# Plot dsolve solution of ODE in MATLAB with multiple constants involved

Tags: matlab, plot, variable-assignment, dsolve

**Basic Goal:**   *Solve* & *Plot* the solution of an ODE 
    `D2f=a1*f+a0`

where

```
a1=k*H*H/c;
a0=-H*H*tau0/c;
c=0.1;
k=1;
H=1;
tau0=1;
```

I am using *dsolve* command to find the solution with the above mentioned values of constants.

```
sol=dsolve('D2th=a1*th+a0','th(0)=0','th(1)=0','t');
```

Instead of getting a solution with assigned values of constants, I get the solution as:

```
sol =


(exp(a1^(1/2)*t)*(a0 - a0*exp(-a1^(1/2))))/(a1*(exp(a1^(1/2)) - exp(-a1^(1/2)))) - (exp(-a1^(1/2)*t)*(a0 - a0*exp(a1^(1/2))))/(a1*(exp(a1^(1/2)) - exp(-a1^(1/2)))) - a0/a1
```

I need MATLAB to automatically replace the values of constants (*a1*, *a0*, etc.,) and then solve the equation, so that the results show up in complete simplified form.

**Secondly**, 
I want to plot the solution of above ODE as follows:

```
t0=0;
tf=1;
N=100;
h=(tf-t0)/N;
t=t0+(0:N)'*h;
plot(t,sol)
```

I have tried `plot(t,sol(t))`
but nothing works fine.

**Summary of question:** first solve the ODE by replacing the values of constant in solution, and then plot the solution with respect to a column vector *t*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a symbolic expression. What you need is substitution in symbolic expressions and plotting of symbolic expressions. A quick search on the Matlab website gives `subs` and `ezplot` as suitable functions. I fixed the code but please check the working of those two functions either on the web or in your Matlab.

```
H=1;
k=1;
c=0.1;
tau0=1;
a1=k*H*H/c;
a0=-H*H*tau0/c;
sol=dsolve('D2th=a1*th+a0','th(0)=0','th(1)=0','t');
sol2 = subs(sol, [sym('a0'),sym('a1')], [a0, a1]);
t0=0;
tf=1;
ezplot(sol2, [t0, tf]);
```

Comment: I am thankful to you for sorting out the problem. Surely, I will check the detials about "subs" and "ezplot".